# Grunt config equivalent to HTML5 boilerplate ant

Tags: gruntjs, html5boilerplate

Is there a Grunt configuration or something equivalent to the html5 boilerplate ant build script (https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script)?

I feel the ant build tool is a lot simpler to use, as you just have to run it, but I'm still just studying these html/javascript/css build tools!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's right there: https://github.com/h5bp/node-build-script ;)
Check the installation instructions in there, looks very easy to get started.

**Important:** I've never used! Just knew about its existence, and they claim to be the closest possible to the ant build script you mentioned.